# Why can I not debug JavaScript and .NET4 code at the same time with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

In VS2008 and the 2.0 CLR, I would almost always attach to both the web server to debug .NET code and Internet Explorer to debug script code.  I could set breakpoints on any layer and it was very easy to track down problems on either tier.

After upgrading to VS2010, I now find I'm no longer able to work this way.  I must choose to either debug script code, or debug .NET code.  It's quite a bit of hassle to keep on "detaching all" and then re-attaching to the other process.

If I try to enable both the .NET debugger and Script debugger, I'll get the following error message:

[image]

**My Question:** What is the technical reason for this limitation (such as an architectural change in the .NET 4.0 runtime) and is there any work around for this?  I've spent some time researching this subject on Google and have found absolutely nothing relevant.  This seems like a *huge* step backwards for Visual Studio!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might help as a workaround:
If you select "options and settings" from the "debug" menu in Visual Studio, is "Just-In-Time" debugging turned on for script? This will be under the "Debugging" menu item, and the "Just-In-Time" sub menu heading - in mine I have 3 options: Managed, Native, and Script and all are selected.

I don't know the technical limitations of VS2010 that might be causing your issue, but the above usually allows me to debug both JavaScript and the .NET code.

Comment: Yes, all three are turned on.  My question is about *why* this limitation exists.

Comment: My apologies, I was responding to the 2nd part of the question, the request for a possible workaround, as I haven't encountered this limitation in VS2010, but thought perhaps my settings would assist (which it appears they didn't). I did some more looking around and there is a blog (http://evan-p.blogspot.com/2010/12/visual-studio-2010-debugger-not.html) that mentions that VS2010 now has two managed code types {v2.0, v1.1, v1.0} and {v4.0} and this has caused the blogger similar issues.